# Is there any way for a cleric to get spontaneous conversion for both cure and inflict?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, cleric

I want to make a cleric who has the ability to spontaneously convert their prepared spells into cure or inflict, not just one of the sides. I am not having any luck in finding anything however. I thought I had read an archetype with this ability, but after reading them I didn't find any. I asked someone who played a cleric who did this, but they were faking it with a wand and I either didn't remember or didn't notice.

Is there a feat, archetype, domain, multiclassing as a cleric while a cleric, or anything that would enable this?

Comment: For those, like me, who are curious: *Why?*

Comment: Never needing to prepare a cure spell is wonderful, and always having damage as well would also be. Having to only prepare ultitily spells or stuff would be helpful.

Comment: Agreed on the *cure* spells, but I've never found having spontaneous *inflict* spells useful except occasionally for the a necromancy-focused cleric; usually spontaneous *inflict* spells are what you suffer with for having access to the awesome spells. But it's cool—I'm down with utility; I was just wondering if you had a plan beyond *I think it'd be handy.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could take 2 levels of the [Envoy of Balance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/envoy-of-balance) Prestige Class to gain an **Endowment** and choose **Spiritual Equilibrium**:

> The envoy of balance’s class levels count as cleric levels for determining the effects of her channel energy ability. If she has the spontaneous casting class feature, she is no longer restricted by the choice made at 1st level to convert prepared spells into cure or inflict spells. Each time the envoy of balance converts a spell, she can choose to convert it into a cure spell or an inflict spell.
>   Additionally, when using the Versatile Channeler feat, her effective cleric level is no longer reduced by 2—instead, she uses her full effective cleric level. An envoy of balance must have the Versatile Channeler feat to choose this endowment.

Answer (score -1):

This could be one option:

[Page of Spell Knowledge (Inflict _____ Wounds)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge/)
*If the bearer is a spontaneous spellcaster and has that spell on her class spell list, she may use her spell slots to cast that spell as if it were one of her spells known.*

Clerics have the Spontaneous Casting class feature, so they qualify for "can cast spells spontaneously." However, I don't think what Page of Spell Knowledge grants will work that way.

With that item, you're able to cast the spell in slots as if you knew it, but it doesn't explicitly let you prepare the spell in your spell slots. The Spontaneous Casting class feature that Clerics get operates irrespective of spells known, so it doesn't seem to matter that the page grants the spell.

There's two cases:

- It lets you prepare spells via a loophole of meeting the requirements.
- It doesn't let you prepare Inflict spells from the page.

Comment: Clerics are prepared casters with the ability to spontaneously convert spells into something. Classes like sorcerer are spontaneous as they have access to all their spells at all times. But the class feature you mention is an interesting point. Under the spells section however "A cleric must choose and prepare her spells in advance."

Comment: @Fering Again, this was the closest thing I could find and it depended on a loophole which depended on interpretation. The "A cleric must choose and prepare her spells in advance." is part of their innate spellcasting, but the Spontaneous Casting class feature is already an exception case. The loose interpretation I posed was that the Cleric qualifies for "can cast spells spontaneously." As a result, the item could allow you to cast that spell from the page using a spell slot,  even though the Spontaneous Casting feature only applies to Cure spells. It's a very weak interpretation.

Comment: Well, I like things based on rules technicalities so Ill give this an upvote. But it will be upto the DM if its allowed to work in such a fashion